# Can a subversion repository be moved, but its mirror remain the same?

Tags: svn, mirroring

I am trying to move a subversion repository to a new server, but leave its mirror where it is.  I have done the following:

1. Dump old repo
2. Load dump into new repo
3. Setup the new repo's post-commit hook to svnsync to the existing mirror

The hook:

```
#!/bin/sh

svnsync --non-interactive sync https://mirror.example.com:443/svn/iaw \
--sync-username svnsyncuser --sync-password svnsyncpass \
--source-username svnsyncuser --source-password svnsyncpass &

exit 0
```

Predictably, when I try to run this hook from the new repo I get the following:

> svnsync: OPTIONS of 'http://oldrepo.url/svn/iaw': Could not resolve hostname `oldrepo.url': Host not found (http://oldrepo.url)

The problem is that the mirror was initialised with the url of the old repo.  Does anyone know if this can be changed, or do I need to start again from scratch with a new mirror?

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Subversion to edit the revision properties on rev 0 of the mirror repository.  I.e.:

```
svn propset --revprop -r0 svn:sync-from-url http://newrepo.url/svn/iaw \
    https://mirror.example.com:443/svn/iaw
```

See the box titled "svnsync Bookkeeping" in the [Repository Replication section of the SVN book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.reposadmin.maint.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.replication).

Answer (score 0):

All your sync information of mirror svn is stored in /repo/db/revprops directory. 
In the directory, you can see files like: 0, 1, 2,

> grep -R "http://oldrepo.url" /repo/db/revprops

and after you find it, modify it to new repo address, and it can work now.

Comment: You should never edit revprop files directly.  Instead, use the SVN command to do this.